# OSGi structure for a project

Tags: java, osgi, modular

I want to develop a system in order to manage readings from a text file. The main structure is based on 4 bundles:

- one to provide a `timestamp` for the `log`
- one to generate/provide the data
- one to keep a `log` (add the `timestamp`and the values to a file)
- one to visualize the generated file with the `timestamp`and the readings

My question is: How should each `bundle` be organized? I'm not 100% familiar with the `OSGi`way of work, it's something I'm working on. My current structure is as follows:

[image]

- the *Interface files are where I have the services to be provided
- the *Activator files are the `bundle` `activator`s, where I register the `service`s
- the *Impl files are used to implement the `interfaces`, although I'm not sure I'm supposed to implement there within the same package

Is it correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right to separate the interfaces into different packages to the implementations. Generally you'll want each bundle to export the packages containing the interfaces, but not the implementation packages. This will help to minimise the coupling between the bundles.

It looks like you have all your services in one project which would result in them all being in the same OSGi bundle. You should probably separate each one out into its own project with its own manifest file. That way the services can be developed and deployed independently and communicate through the service interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Follow up question, if you don't mind. Should I provide an implementation when registering a service? Everywhere I could find information had the interface initialized as a class which implements such interface (in the activator), then the ServiceRegistration registers the service with said class.

Comment: You need to provide an implementation when registering a service, however it's possible to register multiple different implementations using the same service interface, It's worth looking into Declarative Services as that makes the whole job of registering and consuming services much easier.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts. Organize your code into packages first, and bundles second. Assuming that you are expressing dependencies based on packages rather than bundles, it it relatively easy to split a bundle later.

Second, bundle around your intended use and reuse. Is this all part of the same unit? If so, I'd have one API bundle and one or more implementation bundles. If you expect people to mix and match later on (e.g. to use the data file interface separately from the time interface) then those (might) belong in separate bundles.

I see a couple of different things called 'Activator'. An activator manages the lifecycle of a bundle (startup, shutdown, etc). I typically create at most one activator per bundle and place that in an '.internal' package to clarify that it shouldn't escape.

And lastly, keep in mind the difference between library code and application code. If you want to reuse a bundle in different applications (kinda the point), it probably should not spin up its own services (either via an activator or declarative services). Keeping a clean distinction between the application (things that know about and leverage OSGi to assemble a product) and libraries allows you to later re-use your code outside of an OSGi context.